# Is lightning:recordForm support for custom settings?

Tags: lightning, lightning-record-form

I need to create a lightning component to Edit a particular Custom settings Record using the lightning:recordForm. But I couldn't able to achieve it and got the following error. I will share my code below,

[image: The Error I got when I click SAVE button]

Component:

```
<aura:component description="EL_Error_Log_Settings">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" description="The Settings Id" deafult='a073E000005bZ5d'/>
<aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="String[]" default="['Error_Log_Activated__c','Error_Log_Include_Executing_User__c','Error_Log_Recipients__c','Error_Log_Send_Notification_Email__c','Error_Log_Storage_Duration__c']"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleInit}" />

<lightning:card iconName="custom:custom19" title="Edit lightning:recordForm">
    <div class="slds-p-left_large slds-p-right_medium">
        <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                              objectApiName="Sample__Settings__c"
                              columns="2"
                              fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              mode="Edit"
                              onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}"
                              onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}"
                              onload="{!c.onLoad}"
                              onerror="{!c.onError}"
        />

    </div>
</lightning:card>


<soco:EL_Configuration_Service aura:id="ErrorLogService" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
handleInit : function(cmp, event, helper){
    helper.getSampleSettings(cmp, event, helper);
},

onSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "message": "The record has been Saved successfully."
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
},

onSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
},

onLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Loaded!",
        "message": "The record has been Loaded successfully ."
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
},

onError : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Error!",
        "message": "Error."
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
}
})
```

helper

```
({
getSampleSettings : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var service = cmp.find("ErrorLogService");
    service.getCustomSetting().then($A.getCallback(function(response) {
        var responses = response.Error_Log_Activated__c;
        alert(responses);
        var recordId = response.Id;
        alert(recordId);
        cmp.set("v.recordId", recordId);
        })
    );
}
})
```

Please give any suggestions to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From official [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation)

> Supported Objects
>
> This component doesn't support all Salesforce
>   standard objects. For example, the Event and Task objects are not
>   supported.
>
> For a list of supported objects, see the User Interface API Developer
>   Guide.

and reading [Supported Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm) article:

> User Interface API supports all custom objects and many standard
>   objects.

So answer is: no, `lightning:recordForm` dosn't support custom settings

Comment: Yeah correct and got it. Is there any other way to edit a custom settings using predefined lightning component or we need to do this manually?

Comment: @Hariprasath as far as I know, the only option for now is to develop such component manually.